# How to append a new line to a dataframe (previously a dictionary)?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I created a pandas dataframe from a dictionary where the index is the key from the dictionary.

```
data = {'row_1': [1], 'row_2': [2], 'row_3': [3]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')

>>>df
       0
row_1  1
row_2  2
row_3  3

new_row = {'row_4': [4]}
```

How can I append the new row to the df in the same structure?

Comment: if the new rows are coming dynamically then you can create another dataframe from that dictionary and then vertically stack them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
new_row = {"row_4": [4]}

print(df.append(pd.DataFrame(new_row).T))
```

Prints:

```
       0
row_1  1
row_2  2
row_3  3
row_4  4
```

---

Or:

```py
print(df.append(pd.DataFrame(new_row.values(), index=new_row)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'row_1': [1], 'row_2': [2], 'row_3': [3]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
new_row = {'row_4':[4],'row_5':[5]}
df=df.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_row,orient='index'))
print(df)
```